# Tensorflow - Using tf.losses.hinge_loss causing Shapes Incompatible error

Tags: machine-learning, tensorflow, cross-entropy

My current code using `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` works fine.

```py
loss_normal = (
    tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses
                   .sparse_softmax_cross_entropy(labels=labels,
                                                 logits=logits,
                                                 weights=class_weights))
    )
```

However, when I try to use the `hinge_loss`:

```py
loss_normal = (
    tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses
                   .hinge_loss(labels=labels,
                               logits=logits,
                               weights=class_weights))
    )
```

It reported an error saying:

```
ValueError: Shapes (1024, 2) and (1024,) are incompatible
```

The error seems to be originated from this function in the `losses_impl.py` file:

```py
  with ops.name_scope(scope, "hinge_loss", (logits, labels)) as scope:
    ...
    logits.get_shape().assert_is_compatible_with(labels.get_shape())
    ...
```

I modified my code as below to just extract 1 column of the logits tensor:

```py
loss_normal = (
    tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses
                   .hinge_loss(labels=labels,
                               logits=logits[:,1:],
                               weights=class_weights
                               ))
    )
```

But it still reports a similar error:

```
ValueError: Shapes (1024, 1) and (1024,) are incompatible.
```

Can someone please help point out why my code works fine with `sparse_softmax_cross_entropy` loss but not `hinge_loss`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The tensor `labels` has the shape `[1024]`, the tensor `logits` has `[1024, 2]` shape. This works fine for [`tf.nn.sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/nn/sparse_softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits):

> - **labels**: Tensor of shape [d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}] (where r is rank of
>     labels and result) and dtype int32 or int64. Each entry in labels must
>     be an index in [0, num_classes). Other values will raise an exception
>     when this op is run on CPU, and return NaN for corresponding loss and
>     gradient rows on GPU.
> - **logits**: Unscaled log probabilities of shape
>     [d_0, d_1, ..., d_{r-1}, num_classes] and dtype float32 or float64.

But [`tf.hinge_loss`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/losses/hinge_loss) requirements are different:

> - **labels**: The ground truth output tensor. Its shape should match the
>     shape of logits. The values of the tensor are expected to be 0.0 or
>     1.0.
> - **logits**: The logits, a float tensor.

You can resolve this in two ways:

- Reshape the labels to `[1024, 1]` and use just one row of `logits`, like you did - `logits[:,1:]`:

  ```
  labels = tf.reshape(labels, [-1, 1])
  hinge_loss = (
      tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.hinge_loss(labels=labels,
                                          logits=logits[:,1:],
                                          weights=class_weights))
      )
  ```

  I think you'll also need to reshape the `class_weights` the same way.
- Use all of learned `logits` features via `tf.reduce_sum`, which will make a flat `(1024,)` tensor:

  ```
  logits = tf.reduce_sum(logits, axis=1)
  hinge_loss = (
      tf.reduce_mean(tf.losses.hinge_loss(labels=labels,
                                          logits=logits,
                                          weights=class_weights))
      )
  ```

  This way you don't need to reshape `labels` or `class_weights`.

Comment: Thanks Maxim. I'm not sure If i understand the second approach by summing the logics along axis 1. I will try both approaches tomorrow and provide update. Thanks.